# Need help adding months to an age calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im creating an age calculator for my CS class and I need to add a formula where you display how old someone is in years and months.

The year formula is simple by just doing now.year - year however months are much more complicated as python will calculate the distance between the two months as negative. For example if your input month is February instead of it saying you are 8 months away from your birthday it says you are -3 months away from your birthday.

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print ("Current year:", now.year)
print ("Current month:", now. month)

year = int(input("What year were you born in? "))
month = int(input("What month were you born in? "))
agemonth = month - now.month
age = now.year - year
print("Your age is", age)

if age >= 16:
    print("You are old enough to drive")
else:
    print("You are not old enough to drive")

if age >= 21:
    print("You are old enough to drink")
else:
    print("You are not old enough to drink")
```

ideally the program would print you are 8 months away from your birthday if you input February not you are -3 months away from your birthday

Comment: How about an `if` to check if month is negative and if so, fix it?

Comment: You need to handle your if condition by adding 12 to the negative months and subtracting year by 1, check my answer below @ergofye  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using modulo operator:

```
agemonth = (month - now.month) % 12
```

When you're born in January and it's February, that subtraction gives you -1, but its remainder from 12 is 11 that is what we want.

Answer (score 0):

To take care of negative months you need to do two things

- Add 12 to number of months to make it positive, or take `%12`, so `-4` becomes 8
- Decrease year by 1
  You can also simplify your latter `if` statements

Considering these two changes, The code becomes

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print ("Current year:", now.year)
print ("Current month:", now. month)

year = int(input("What year were you born in? "))
month = int(input("What month were you born in? "))
agemonth = now.month - month
age = now.year - year

#If months are negative
if agemonth < 0:
    #Take modulo 12 of agemonth to make it positive
    agemonth = agemonth%12
    #Subtract 1 from year
    age = age - 1

print("Your age is ", age, "years and", agemonth, 'months')

#3 If statements based on ages
if age <= 16:
    print("You are not old enough to drive")
    print("You are not old enough to drink")
elif 16 < age < 21:
    print("You are old enough to drive")
    print("You are not old enough to drink")
else:
    print("You are old enough to drive")
    print("You are old enough to drink")
```

Possible outputs are

```
Current year: 2019
Current month: 5
What year were you born in? 1991
What month were you born in? 1
Your age is  28 years and 4 months
You are old enough to drive
You are old enough to drink

Current year: 2019
Current month: 5
What year were you born in? 2005
What month were you born in? 8
Your age is  13 years and 9 months
You are not old enough to drive
You are not old enough to drink

Current year: 2019
Current month: 5
What year were you born in? 2001
What month were you born in? 1
Your age is  18 years and 4 months
You are old enough to drive
You are not old enough to drink
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that you have said for someone having birthday in Feb, the output should indicate their birthday is 8 months away, the correct formula should be:

```
    agemonth = (month-now.month-1)%12 
    #month = 2, now.month = 5. Thus agemonth = 8
```

This will always give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date

year = int(input("What year were you born in? "))
month = int(input("What month were you born in? "))

today = date.today()
age = today.year - year
agemonth = today.month - month
totmonth = 0
if  agemonth >= 0:
  totmonth = agemonth 
else:
  agemonth = 12 + agemonth 
  age -= 1

print "age is" , age,"years and", agemonth,"months"
if age <= 16:
  print("You are not old enough to drive")
  print("You are not old enough to drink")
elif 16 < age < 21:
  print("You are old enough to drive")
```

> **Output :**
>
> What year were you born in? 1999
>
> What month were you born in? 7
>
> age is 19 years and 11 months
>
> You are old enough to drive
>
> You are not old enough to drink